# Filter table view by distance from user location

Tags: uitableview, cllocationmanager, cllocationcoordinate2d

I have a table view that is being populated with a name from a mysql database, I want to filter the table by closest distance to the users location. The data Im retrieving has coordinate values which I want to use as the distance.

```
Route * routeObject; //data from mysql

CGFloat latitude = [routeObject.startLat doubleValue];
CGFloat longitude = [routeObject.startLong doubleValue];

CLLocationCoordinate2D startCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
```

Im getting the users location like this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    if (newLocation)
    {
        if ((oldLocation.coordinate.latitude != newLocation.coordinate.latitude) &&
           (oldLocation.coordinate.longitude != newLocation.coordinate.longitude))

            self.userCoord = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.userCoord);
    }
}
```

Now Im having trouble filtering the table, I don't know/understand how to organise the cells by distance to user location any ideas?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Route * routeObject;
    routeObject = [routesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = routeObject.name;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Basically, you have to sort the datasource (ie. routesArray in your case) and then call reloadData.  Here's one way to sort the array by distance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472333/objective-c-sort-array-using-arguments

Comment: do you still need support?

Comment: @user3071962 Yes, currently trying work on the previous comment.